# How to insert/update rows from MySQL to SQL Server by using SSIS

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis, ado.net

I'm looking for the best practice to insert or update rows from a MySQL connection to a SQL Server connection.

[image]

First of all, I added a ADO.NET data source to grab MySQL content (a simple table Supplier with two fields id and name). Then, I added a Lookup transformation to split new rows / updated rows. It works well when I need to insert new rows. However, I would like to use a Command OLE DB to update existing rows but It doesn't work due to a incompatibility between my connection manager and the component (ADO.NET vs OLE DB).

Any idea to update modified rows ?! Should I use a cache component ?!

Thanks in advance !

Comment: possible duplicate of [Updating records in MYSQL with SSIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111766/updating-records-in-mysql-with-ssis)

Comment: This post explains how to update data from SQL Server to MySQL by using SSIS. However, due to constraints about connectors (ADO.NET / OLE DB) the process is more complex to import from MySQl to SQL Server than from SQL Server to MySQL.

Comment: Can't you just do the same thing, in reverse? Using an OLE DB target connection for the SQL Server database in a staging table, then running an UPDATE or MERGE against the final table?

Comment: Ok. So, first of all I need to create a new SQL Server connection to store my staging table, then to connect the matching rows output (of the Lookup component) to a new destination OLE DB compoment (linked to my staging table).

Secondly, I need to add a new data flow to read the staging table, to execute a OLE DB command to update content.
However, I don't understand how to link these to steps.
Should I crete two data flows and add a priority constraint to execute the import before the export ?
Moreover, how can I create the staging table with SSIS and troncate it after at the end ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get rid of the lookup and conditional split all together.

Outside of your SSIS package, build a staging table that contains the fields you need for inserts/updates.

In your SSIS Package, create a control flow that does the following:

- Execute SQL Task to truncate the staging table.
- Data Flow task to load the MySQL data from the source system to the staging table. If you can do this based on a "changes-only" type process, such as using a timestamp that you check, it would be faster.
- Execute SQL Task to perform an UPDATE statement on your target table using the staging table joined to the target table.
- Execute SQL Task to perform an INSERT statement on your target table using a query based on the target table and your staging table (with a WHERE NOT EXISTS or some such on a key fied)

Answer (score 0):

I would change the SQL connection to use OLE DB.  As well as allowing the OLE DB Command to work, you may also find the OLE DB Destination is faster.

Comment: It seems the only way to use a OLE DB command is to change to a OLE DB data source. However, MySQL is not compatible with OLE DB data sources. That's why I used a ADO.NET source to grab data from MySQL.