# how to upsert data from mysql to ssms using ssis

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis, ssms, upsert

how can we insert new data or update the data from one table to another table from MySQL to SQL server using ssis and by not using lookup.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981867/how-to-insert-update-rows-from-mysql-to-sql-server-by-using-ssis and https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2613/export-data-from-mysql-to-sql-server/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert/update rows from MySQL to SQL Server by using SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22981867/how-to-insert-update-rows-from-mysql-to-sql-server-by-using-ssis)

Answer (score 0):

A common way to do this is to insert new data to an empty temporary table, and then run SQL Merge command (using separate SQL Query task).

MERGE command is super powerful and can do updates, inserts or even deletes. See full description of Merge here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

The design for this will look like below :

You will have 4 tables and 1 view : Source, TMP_Dest (exactly as source with no PK), CHG_Dest(for changes, exactly as destination with no PK), Dest(will have PK), FV_TMP_Dest (this is in case the destination looks different than the source - different field types)

SSIS package :

1.Use ExecuteSQLTask and truncate TMP_Dest because it is just temporary for the extracted data

Use ExecuteSQlTask and truncate CHG_Dest because it is just temporary for the extracted data

Use one DataFlowTask for loading data from Source to TMP_Dest

Define two variables OperationIDInsert=1 and OperationIDUpdate=2 (the values are not important, you can set them as you want) -> you will use them at 5. point below

Use another DataFlowTask in which you will have:

on the left side OLE DB Source in which you will extract data from the view, ordered by PK (do not forget to set the SortKeyPosition from Advanced Editor for the PK fields)

on the right side OLE DB Source in which you will extract data from the Dest ordered by PK (do not forget to set the SortKeyPosition from Advanced Editor for the PK fields)

LEFT JOIN between this

on the left side ( "insert side") you will have: a derived column in which you will assign as Expression the OperationIDInsert variable AND an OLE DB Destination for inserting the data in CHG_Dest table. In this way, you will insert the data that have to be inserted in the destination table and you know this because you have the OperationIDInsert column.

on the right side you will do the same thing but using OperationIDUpdate column

You will use ExecuteSQLTask in the ControlFlow and will have an SQL Merge. Based on the PK fields and OperationIDInsert/OperationIDUpdate fields you will either insert the data or update it.

Hope this will help you. Let me know if you need additional info.